# async.each not giving the result?

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

This is my code:

```
 var shopId=[1,2,3,4];
  async.each(shopId,function (item,callback) {
     model.client.query("SELECT categoryId shopId=? ", [shopId], function (err, rows) {
        if (rows.length > 0) {
          var asyncData = rows;
          //categoryId will be in the format [1,2,3,4]
          async.each(asyncData,function (item, callback) {
            var categoryId = item.categoryId;
            async.series([
                function (callback) {
                  model.client.query("select categoryName from category  where categoryId = ?", [categoryId], function (err, data) {
                  callback(null, data);
                  });
                }],
                 function (err, results) {
                 item.category = results[0];
                 callback();
                 });
            },function (err) {
             callback(asyncData);  //getting data here
            });
        }
    });
 },function (err,result) {
res.json(result);  //not getting data here
});
```

I am new to aysnc methods. I am not able to pass the result to final function.

Comment: You can declare an object above the first `async` block and then append any of the results to it and in the final callback use this. If you are using express, you can use `req` object for the same. But you must break this code block in multiple middleware, it's quite nested and thus more error-prone and difficult to understand.

Comment: Use `async.map` instead of `each`

Comment: are you using mysql ? i think you code can get much cleaner

Comment: @Jérôme ya , i am using my sql

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that there is a `shop` table, you can join your tables to save a query.

`const sql = 'select categoryName from category as c inner join shop as s on c.categoryId = s.categoryId where s.shopId = ?'`

then

```
const shopId = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const finalResult = [];
async.each(shopId, function(item, callback) {
  model.client.query(sql, [shopId], function (err, rows) {
    // do not forget error handling !
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      finalResult.push(rows);
      return callback();
    }
    return callback(); // do not forget to return callback in every case
  });
}, function(err) { // in async each callback, you only get errors
  if (err)
    return res.json(err); // or whatever error handling
  res.json(finalResult);
});
```

Also, considering your code, I would advise to name differently your callbacks to avoid errors or forgets. i.e.

```
async.each([], function(item, cbkGlobal) {
  async.each([], function(item, cbkEach) {});
});
```

And `async.series` is usefull when you want **multiple** functions to get execute in order. But here you are executing only one function...